# For loop for Pyramid of Circles in Processing/Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, drawing, processing

I am trying to draw a pyramid of 10 circles in processing and I can't figure out a good way to condense this code into a clean loop. The `lights[c].display()` function simply draws an ellipse and some text at the center of the current translation. I'd like to keep the `gap` variable as something I can use to update the spacing between the circles. I just haven't figured out how to increment the rows and columns in a way that results in a pyramid. There will always be 10 circles. Thanks for your help!

---

[image]

---

```
int gap = 30;

public void display() {
  int c = 0;
  pushMatrix();
    translate(0, 0);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(-gap, 2*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(gap, 2*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(-2*gap, 4*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(0, 4*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(2*gap, 4*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(-3*gap, 6*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(-gap, 6*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(gap, 6*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
    translate(3*gap, 6*gap);
    lights[c++].display();
  popMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can begin from this simply solution

```
int[] tx = new int[]{0, -1, 1, ...};
int[] ty = new int[]{0, 2, 2, ...};

for(int c = 0; c < circlesCount; c++) {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(tx[c] * gap, ty[c] * gap);
  lights[c].display();
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: That certainly helps!